# Spring OAuth2 - Manually creating an access token in the token store

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a situation where I would like to create an access token myself (so not through the usual process). I have come up with something like this:

```
@Inject
private DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices;

... 

OAuth2Authentication auth = xxx;
OAuth2AccessToken  token = defaultTokenServices.createAccessToken(auth);
```

The only problem is that I am not sure how to create the OAuth2Authentication (in my code the part with xxx). I have the user & client info and I know which Authorities I want to grant this token.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here it is, your use case may differ slightly based on the flow you are using. This is what works for a password grant flow. There are a few custom class like token store, token enhancer ect. but that is really just extended versions of the spring classes modified for our own needs.

```
        HashMap<String, String> authorizationParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        authorizationParameters.put("scope", "read");
        authorizationParameters.put("username", "mobile_client");
        authorizationParameters.put("client_id", "mobile-client");
        authorizationParameters.put("grant", "password");

        DefaultAuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = new DefaultAuthorizationRequest(authorizationParameters);
        authorizationRequest.setApproved(true);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_UNTRUSTED_CLIENT"));
        authorizationRequest.setAuthorities(authorities);

        HashSet<String> resourceIds = new HashSet<String>();
        resourceIds.add("mobile-public");
        authorizationRequest.setResourceIds(resourceIds);

        // Create principal and auth token
        User userPrincipal = new User(user.getUserID(), "", true, true, true, true, authorities);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, authorities) ;

        OAuth2Authentication authenticationRequest = new OAuth2Authentication(authorizationRequest, authenticationToken);
        authenticationRequest.setAuthenticated(true);

        CustomTokenStore tokenStore = new CustomTokenStore();

        // Token Enhancer
        CustomTokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer = new CustomTokenEnhancer(user.getUserID());

        CustomTokenServices tokenServices = new CustomTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer);
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenServices.createAccessTokenForUser(authenticationRequest, user);
```

Comment: What is DefaultAuthorizationRequest here?

Comment: This isn't very helpful without import statements.

Answer (score 16):

Here is how to generate a Token using the TokenEndpoint interface (used to expose REST service) :

```
@Inject
private TokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint;

public ResponseEntity<?> getToken(Principal principal) {

        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("client_id", "appid");
        parameters.put("client_secret", "myOAuthSecret");
        parameters.put("grant_type", "password");
        parameters.put("password", myUser.getPassword());
        parameters.put("scope", "read write");
        parameters.put("username", myUser.getLogin());

        return tokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(principal, parameters);
}
```

Comment: `getAccessToken` won't work for newer versions of spring-security-oauth2-2.x.x, unless you call `tokenEndpoint.setAllowedRequestMethods(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.GET))` first. Since `getAccessToken` calls `postAccessToken` under the hood, you could call `postAccessToken` right away.

Comment: @Inject TokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint getting null tokenEndpoint

Answer (score 11):

Other way, to manually generate an `OAuth2 Accesss Token` we can use an instance of `TokenService`

```
@Autowired
private AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration configuration;

@Override
public String generateOAuth2AccessToken(User user, List<Role> roles, List<String> scopes) {

    Map<String, String> requestParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, Serializable> extensionProperties = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();

    boolean approved = true;
    Set<String> responseTypes = new HashSet<String>();
    responseTypes.add("code");

    // Authorities
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for(Role role: roles)
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()));

    OAuth2Request oauth2Request = new OAuth2Request(requestParameters, "clientIdTest", authorities, approved, new HashSet<String>(scopes), new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("resourceIdTest")), null, responseTypes, extensionProperties);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), "N/A", authorities);

    OAuth2Authentication auth = new OAuth2Authentication(oauth2Request, authenticationToken);

    AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenService = configuration.getEndpointsConfigurer().getTokenServices();

    OAuth2AccessToken token = tokenService.createAccessToken(auth);

    return token.getValue();
}
```

Comment: with this approach we can access the resources with generated access token, on expiring access token it wont issue access token with refresh token. it gives Unauthorized client, even if the client details are correct

Comment: It gives me Field tokenService in com.demo.sas.service.UserLoginService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.token.TokenService' that could not be found. I am using TokenService with the @Autowired annoation.

Answer (score 4):

I based my solution on Mop So's answer but instead of using:

```
return tokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(principal, parameters);
```

I used:

```
tokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(principal, parameters);
```

Why? Because if you use `tokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(principal, parameters)` the endpoing will throw you a `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` because it has not been called with a `GET` method. At least, this is what happened to me with `spring-security-oauth2-2.0.13.RELEASE`

```
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken() throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
    parameters.put("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET);
    parameters.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    ClientDetails clientDetails = clientDetailsStore.get(CLIENT_ID);

    // Create principal and auth token
    User userPrincipal = new User(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, true, true, true, true, clientDetails.getAuthorities());

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, CLIENT_SECRET,
            clientDetails.getAuthorities());

    ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> accessToken = tokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(principal, parameters);

    return accessToken.getBody();
}
```

Comment: You could set TokenEndpoint's allowed request methods beforehand: `tokenEndpoint.setAllowedRequestMethods(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.GET))`, but since `getAccessToken` calls `postAccessToken` under the hood, your way is the way to go. Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

I had problems with all the implementations listed here, so I finally managed to get my own with a stateless server, oauth2 and google social. Its just the last part of the tutorial that is missing [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-5-oauth-20-login-and-signup-in-sta)

The problem for me is that after executing the google oauth, I need to exchange a 10 second duration token for a long lived token. In order to do that I need to generate a JWT token and exchange it with a real access token generated by myself.

## Implementation

```
@Service
class SocialTokenVerificationService {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jwsTokenService: JWSTokenService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var clientDetailsService: ClientDetailsService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userService: UserService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var tokenServices: DefaultTokenServices
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var tokenRequestFactory: OAuth2RequestFactory

    fun verifyToken(token: String): OAuth2AccessToken? {
        val claimSet = jwsTokenService.parseToken(token)
        val userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(claimSet.subject)

        val client = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(DEFAULT_SERVER_CLIENT)
        val parameters = HashMap<String, String>()
        val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities)
        return tokenServices.createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication(
                tokenRequestFactory.createOAuth2Request(client, TokenRequest(parameters, client.clientId, listOf("read", "write"), "password")),
                authentication
        ))
    }
}
```

- `JWSTokenService`: its a self implemented class that encodes and decodes the exchanging token between google oauth and mine.
- `ClientDetailsService`: bean declared as as part of the authorization server. Comes from my database

  override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) {
      clients.jdbc(datasource)
  }
- `UserService`: just a user service that extends `UserDetailsService` to obtain my users from the database
- `DefaultTokenServices`: implemented as a primary bean as follows

  ```
  @Bean
  @Primary
  fun tokenServices(): DefaultTokenServices {
      val defaultTokenServices = DefaultTokenServices()
      defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore())
      defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true)
      defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
      return defaultTokenServices
  }
  ```
- `OAuth2RequestFactory`: implemented as a bean as follows

  ```
  @Bean
  fun oauthRequestFactory(clientsDetails: ClientDetailsService): OAuth2RequestFactory {
      return DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientsDetails)
  }
  ```

With all this dependencies, what I need to do to generate a token that gets stored into the database and follows the same flows as the other ones without providing a password is:

1. Parse the jws token and verify its validity
2. Load the user that was authenticated with google
3. Generate an `Authentication` using the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` class. This is the key part, call `DefaultTokenServices#createAccessToken` to obtain a new token. It needs some arguments to execute the request:

   - `OAuth2Request`: it can be created with the `OAuth2RequestFactory`
   - The `Authentication` created previously
   - We need to generate a `TokenRequest` with the client that is triggering this token request. In my case I have that hardcoded

## Summary

So to recap how to create a token manually:

- We need to ask the token services to give us a token
- For that we need to provide the authentication details and a client who does the request
- With those 2 we can obtain a new token and serve it normally

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
@Override public OAuth2AccessToken getToken(String username, String password) {
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("client_id", clientid);
    parameters.put("grant_type", "password");
    parameters.put("password", username);
    parameters.put("scope", scope);
    parameters.put("username", password);

    AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = defaultOAuth2RequestFactory.createAuthorizationRequest(parameters);
    authorizationRequest.setApproved(true);

    OAuth2Request oauth2Request = defaultOAuth2RequestFactory.createOAuth2Request(authorizationRequest);
    // Create principal and auth token
    final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loginToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            username, password);
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(loginToken);

    OAuth2Authentication authenticationRequest = new OAuth2Authentication(oauth2Request, authentication);
    authenticationRequest.setAuthenticated(true);

    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenServices.createAccessToken(authenticationRequest);

    return accessToken;
}
```

In the Oauth2Configuration:

```
@Bean
    DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory defaultOAuth2RequestFactory() {
    return new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
}
```

The rest of the Oauth2Configuration should look like in the article:

http://stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/

Comment: I´m having BadCredentialsExcepton .. how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In a spring boot 2.2.2 project I'm using the following code to do a pasword flow server side:
I had to specify `authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper` since `PasswordOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider` is expecting specific attributes in the context. Hope that helps.

Config (application.yaml):

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          yourOauthProvider:
            user-info-uri: ...
            authorization-uri: ...
            token-uri: ...

        registration:
          regId:
            clientId: ...
            clientSecret: ...
            provider: yourOauthProvider
            authorization-grant-type: password
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope:
```

Wiring:

```
@Configuration
public class Oauth2ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .password()
                        .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(r -> {
            Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
            m.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, r.getPrincipal().getPrincipal());
            m.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, r.getPrincipal().getCredentials());
            return m;
        });

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
class AuthService {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;
    public OAuth2AccessToken authenticate(String user, String password) {

        Authentication principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user,
                password);

        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = 
            OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("regId")
                .principal(principal)
                .build();

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient =
            this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);

        return authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
    }
}
```