# Spring OAuth2 - Create an access token

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm using the method here described to create an OAuth2 access token:

[Spring OAuth2 - Manually creating an access token in the token store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536521/spring-oauth2-manually-creating-an-access-token-in-the-token-store)

This method works with spring-security-oauth2 1.0.5.RELEASE but it doesn't work with spring-security-oauth2 2.0.6.RELEASE.

Is there a way to make the same thing with spring-security-oauth2 2.0.6.RELEASE?

Answer (score 9):

Here is example Rest Controller method that works with spring-security-oauth2 2.0.6.RELEASE

```
@RequestMapping("/token")
public OAuth2AccessToken token(Principal principal) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

    Map<String, String> requestParameters = new HashMap<>();
    String clientId = "acme";
    boolean approved = true;
    Set<String> scope = new HashSet<>();
    scope.add("scope");
    Set<String> resourceIds = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> responseTypes = new HashSet<>();
    responseTypes.add("code");
    Map<String, Serializable> extensionProperties = new HashMap<>();

    OAuth2Request oAuth2Request = new OAuth2Request(requestParameters, clientId,
            authorities, approved, scope,
            resourceIds, null, responseTypes, extensionProperties);


    User userPrincipal = new User(principal.getName(), "", true, true, true, true, authorities);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, authorities);
    OAuth2Authentication auth = new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Request, authenticationToken);
    OAuth2AccessToken token = defaultTokenServices.createAccessToken(auth);
    return token;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For those that come after me: you need to wire your defaultTokenServices yourself, injecting it will wire the wrong instance.

Comment: DefaultTokenServices service = new DefaultTokenServices();
OAuth2AccessToken token = service.createAccessToken(auth);

Comment: InMemoryTokenStore inMemoryTokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();  service.setTokenStore(inMemoryTokenStore);    /* you may want to make inMemoryTokenStore a final static or similar for scope */ (to add to Kumaresan addition)