# How to generate an oauth token using spring without the password

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to create an additional access token for a user within my spring boot application. I do not know their password but the user is authorized to the application. From what I can see I would need to call something like

```
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenServices.createAccessTokenForUser(authenticationRequest, user);
```

Where tokenServices is presumably an instance of DefaultTokenServices. The question is how do I get a reference to the configured token services? I see that this is wired into AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer but I cannot autowire this in. I am using JWT for authentication so really looking for a way to generate a JWT token.

Was trying to implement the flow outlined in [Spring OAuth2 - Manually creating an access token in the token store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536521/spring-oauth2-manually-creating-an-access-token-in-the-token-store)

Answer (score 0):

In my spring-security-config.xml i have this:

```
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.oauth2.token.provider.HybrisOAuthTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="refreshTokenValiditySeconds" value="2592000" />
        <!-- 60*60*24*30 = 30d -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="43200" />
        <!-- 60*60*12 = 12h -->
    </bean>
```

Where i can configure my customized tokenServices

```
public class HybrisOAuthTokenServices extends DefaultTokenServices{

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(final OAuth2Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{
        try{
            return super.createAccessToken(authentication);
        }catch (final ModelSavingException e) {
            //in case when other client was faster in saving access token - try to get token again
            return super.createAccessToken(authentication);
        }catch (final ModelRemovalException e) {
            //in case when other client was faster in removing expired token - try to get token again
            return super.createAccessToken(authentication);
        }
    }

}
```