# Spring boot oauth2 - Access token too long

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a project user java spring boot and oauth2. Access token is very too long. 

 How to set length of access token. Thanks for help

Comment: I don't think you will get another answer until you provide more details in your question. My answer fits the question as its described so far. And i doubt that someone will invest time into an answer just to have you tell them, that you don't use X but use Y for task Z.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using mostly default configuration and therefore the [DefaultTokenServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html) builds your access token.

Since spring is completely open source you can look easily into their code and find [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java#L293) line:

```
DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

There is no option to specify the length of your access token. An option would be to implement a token service by yourself and create an access token in a way you want to.

There is already [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536521/spring-oauth2-manually-creating-an-access-token-in-the-token-store) that asks how to create a custom oauth2 token. Maybe this helps you doing this.

But be careful when implementing this by yourself, because this is in fact your security token. If it is weak, your authentication is weak.

Comment: Yep I see it,
If normal, oauth2 access token is a UUID ramdom, but I add JWT token with key store :)) it make access token too long.

Comment: That would be an information worth to be mentioned in your question ;)

Comment: Now, what do you mean with the token is too long ? You mean it doesn't fit somewhere ?