# How to change an additional information of jwt access token

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, jwt

I'm working with *Spring Security* and use *JWT* as access token , When a client sends the access token to server I must change an additional information (metadata) of this token and return a new one.

How can I achieve that ?

i try with this code but not working

```java
        String authorization = Context.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authorization != null) {
            String tokenValue = authorization.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            accessToken.getAdditionalInformation().put("activeProfileId", defaultProfileId);
            return accessToken.getValue();
        }

        return null;
```

Comment: What spring-security-oauth2 version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get your metadata ("claims") from the token, then add them to a new JWT builder that will return a new token. The new JWT must be entered in HttpResponse to forward it to the client. Instead, the client will have to implement an interceptor to retrieve it in a comfortable and transparent way.

You've to get all Additional Information as HashMap and place them in OAuth2Authentication. stackoverflow.com/a/19057480/11951081

In ajax should be:

https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', <Jwt>)
    },
    success:function(event,jqXHR,ajaxOptions,data ){
        console.log(ajaxOptions.getResponseHeader('Authorization'))
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you for answer but how can generate jwt token from current token ?

Comment: You've to get all Additional Information as HashMap and place them in OAuth2Authentication.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19057480/11951081